# Raspberry pi and access without monitor

Tags: pi-3, wifi, ssh

I would like to buy a raspberry Pi 3 to be used in my company in a research project. 
Since I don't have a second monitor to connect the device to, I would like to control it via wifi (my laptop is connected to the company network via LAN, so I can easily use wifi for Pi).

I can't connect the Pi to the company network, for various reasons, so I would like to know which possibilities I have to control it via wifi. 
Ad hoc connection? 
Or it's easier if I buy a wireless access point and create a small network among my laptop and the pi?

EDIT: just found this nice guide for direct connection: https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still have to provide some wifi credentials so if I were you I'd buy a router and create my own local network with ethernet connection to pi and wifi connection to your computer. You can then see (from router admin panel) which IP address was assigned to your Raspberry Pi and connect to it via ssh.

Comment: Thanks @Mark! Anyway, why you see a problem in providing Wifi credential? I have admin privileges in my company laptop, so no problem for it

Comment: @Val because if you boot your Pi with fresh install without display and ethernet connection, how would you connect to it via ssh to set things up? Pi won't know the SSID even if the network is completely open. But if you connect it via ethernet, your Pi should get it's address from DHCP on router and you will be able to find it on this local network.

Comment: You could configure the Pi as an WiFi AP and connect your laptops wifi to it direclty, no need for an extra device.

Comment: yes but how I connect to it the first time in order to configure it? @onion

Comment: @Val you could always go with pi to somebody with a router, configure it and go back home

Comment: yes, not the best solution but ok..

Comment: If you can access a linux system then you can mount root fs from the SD card and make any modifications directly on it.Or attach the Pi to your laptop with cross-over cable and use that if you can configure your laptop to provide an IP over dhcp.